# postgis linestring segmentation in 4326

Tags: postgis, linestring, splitting

How can I divide a single postgis linestring with SRID 4326 into segments (preferably an array of linestrings) with no segment longer than a given distance? I've tried st_segmentize(), but it spits out another single linstring.

Comment: What do you mean by "another single linestring". One with the same number of points as the input, or a dense one with lots of new points?

Comment: yes, I mean a dense one with new points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks simplexio. I've solved this problem by modifying your procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION segmentize() 
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    i INTEGER;
    wanted_len double precision;
    start_fract double precision;
    end_fract double precision;
    num_segments INTEGER;
    tmp_line GEOMETRY;

BEGIN
    wanted_len:=100;
    unique_id:=1;

    FOR rec IN
        SELECT length, the_geom, gid FROM lines WHERE length > wanted_len
    LOOP
        num_segments:=ceil(rec.len/wanted_len);

        FOR i IN 0..(num_segments-1)
        LOOP
            start_fract := (wanted_len/rec.len)*i;
            end_fract := (wanted_len/rec.len)*(i+1);

            IF end_fract > 1 
            THEN 
                end_fract:=1;
            END IF;

            tmp_line:=st_line_substring( rec.the_geom, start_fract, end_fract );

            INSERT INTO cutted_lines(
                gid,
                length,
                the_geom
            ) 
            VALUES (
                    rec.gid,
                    rec.the_geom,
                    rec.length
                    );

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PostGIS 2.1 or later, [ST_Segmentize](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) for the geography type was introduced:

```
ST_Segmentize(geography geog, float max_segment_length)
```

Where `geog` is a geography object, similar to a geometry with SRID=4326, and `max_segment_length` is a distance in metres. If you don't want to use geography types, you can cast between like this:

```
SELECT ST_Segmentize(geom::geography, 1000)::geometry AS geom;
```

Answer (score 2):

see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html 8.10 linear referencing
[ST_Segmentize](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Segmentize.html) probably uses degree when used with srid 4326, have tried converting data to srid which uses meters ?

If that does not work , you could try code below

geometry ST_Line_Substring(geometry a_linestring, float startfraction, float endfraction);

You need to do procedure which goes something like this

```
DECLARE rec RECORD; 
DECALRE i integer ; 
FOR rec IN
  SELECT ST_Length(geom) as len, geom, gid FROM lines 
LOOP
  RETURN NEXT rec
    FOR i IN 
      (SELECT ceil(rec.len/wanted_len))
    LOOP
      SELECT ST_Line_Substring(rec.geom, (1/((rec.len/wanted_len)*i))), (1/((rec.len/wanted_len)*i))) as geom, i as part, rec.gid as gid INTO cut_lines 
    END LOOP;
END LOOP
```

Code probably doesn't work and it assumes that substring doesn't complain end fraction being over 1 (which can be fixed with CASE OR IF ELSE )